# Custom camera Android preview picture is different from show picture

Tags: android, camera

I am working on an Android app that uses the phone's camera and I'm using a custom code.

The problem is that the image is showing in the preview is not correct (the image aspect ratio is not OK).

If I use the following code:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

   Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
   List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
   Camera.Size selected = sizes.get(0);
   params.setPreviewSize(selected.width,selected.height);
   mCamera.setParameters(params);
   mCamera.startPreview();
```

the preview image is OK (I think little part of the image top and bottom is not showed).

The problem then is that the captured image showed after takePicture method is called is not showed  correctly (the image aspect ratio is not OK, the image appears to be compressed into the view), even so if I save the picture to a file image appears to be OK.

I wonder if it is possible to show the image correctly in both cases. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was easy, but I didn't know **I must set correct aspect ratio MANUALLY** (it is not an automatic process, I supposed it was and this step it is not explained in most how to's). Finally, I solved it this way:

1. Getting supported sizes using `params.getSupportedPreviewSizes()` and `params.getSuppertedPictureSize()`.
2. **Computing the best aspect ratio** (width/height) according to the measures `width` and `height` passed in `surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)`.
3. Setting the best preview size and picture size using `setPreviewSize`and `setPictureSize`, respectively, before `startPreview()` method is called.

Comment: take a look at open camera the Code for the aspect Ratio is not the worst. but you can clean it a bit up

Answer (score 0):

If you saved the image and it appears correctly, the problem isn't the image being taken, it's how you're displaying it back to the user. If you're using an ImageView, make sure you're using src (not background), as src will keep the aspect ratio, but background will stretch and distort the image to fill the background. Likewise, you can set android:adjustViewBounds="true" to have the ImageView adjust its boundaries to preserve the aspect ratio.

Comment: Is just what you say. But I'm not using and ImageView, because the image is displayed automatically after takePicture method is called, so I think the image is displayed in the surface. How can I control that?

Comment: You should show the code for how you're taking the picture and what you do with it afterwards, as without that information I can't help you

Comment: I'm taking the picture from my activity class using    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, image); where 'image' is the PictureCallback. By the moment, I'm not doing nothing with the pictures afterwards. I've implemented a SurfaceView in another class, where are declared the methods surfaceCreated and surfaceChanged (the last one as I explained above).

Comment: As I explained, when the method takePicture is called, the picture (whose aspect ratio is not correct) is displayed back to the user for a few seconds and then (live) preview is showed again.